# how to get data from website on search option using python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to extract data from website
http://maps.jocogov.org/ims/

In this website there is an search option, In that search option I want to get information corresponding to specific propertyids like DP14000001 0001

When we search property id, a pop up windows appear and from that window, I need to extract data from this link "Tax Bill Info Click Here"

I'm storing the propertyids in text file so that ids could itearte from there and used in search option and getting data from the link in pop up window.

I'm new to web scraping and written some starting code...

```
import re
import urllib

propertyids = "/home/NewYork/PropertyId.txt"

url = "http://maps.jocogov.org/ims/"
htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
htmltext = htmlfile.read()
regex = 'class="ui-autocomplete-input" type="+propertyids+"'
pattern = re.compile(regex)
locationidinfo = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)

print locationidinfo
```

After executing this code am getting result like this [ ], dont know what it  means. So I'm lost in setting up further code to get data from website...

Can anyone assist to step further ?

Thank in advance !! :)

Comment: `[]` is an empty list. Be sure the pattern you're using isn't neglecting all of your scraped data.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye, Am I going in right direction from the code I have written above? I got that now [] means empty list, but I think I've passed the right regex for the same. But do you think somewhere code needs where it press submit button on passing propertyid in search option ?

Comment: I mean, like we manually enters a propertyid in search option and press search option to get result..Do we need to do in the code that way ?

Comment: On this url, http://taxbill.jocogov.org/...Is my regex is right regex = '<input id="txtParcelID" type="text" name="+propertyids+"></input>' for passing propertyid cos am receiving [] every time..

Comment: It seems that the "pop up" window that opens in the site is another HTML frame, so, maybe you are not scrapping the data from the right page, because the link of the main page is different than the one of the frame